how to use the long value by csv data set config
i am testing on a API and the response for the get request is given in the format of JSON. so by using JSON extractor i extracted the required data for my next sampler requests. the configuration of JSON extractor looks like this
Names of created variable = PET_ID
JSON path Expressions = $..[*].[?(@.name == 'doggie')].id
Match No. = -1
Default values = ERROR 

by using the jsr223 post processor i stored the extracted values into a csv data set file and the code looks like this:
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
// Get total number of matches. (Returns string)
def path = "C:/Users/M Rakesh/Downloads/JMETER/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/test_csv_files/results.csv"
def resultCount = vars.get("PET_ID_matchNr")
log.warn 'Output to jmeter console ' +  resultCount
// Generate timestamp to create uniue file name.
// String fileSuffix = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm").format(new Date())
// Create file Object
f = new File("test_csv_files/results.csv")

for (int i=1; i<=resultCount.toInteger(); i++)
{
  // Get each matching result one by one.
  records = vars.get("PET_ID_"+i)
// Write result to csv file.
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f,records + System.getProperty("line.separator"),true)
}

the stored values look like this 
i cannot use the values which are stored in the csv file due to the data type and it is not showing the full id number
here are my questions:

i want to store the full id number and use it later
i want delete the data after the test execution is completed and recreate the csv file before the test execution. in this way i can save some storage while doing the test in load testing.

thank in advance for your help...!!

You can use the values, it's Excel which displays the numbers in scientific format, so you just need to format cells accordingly. See How to change the scientific number time format
With regards to removing the file once it has been used you can do this using i.e. tearDown Thread Group, JSR223 Sampler and the following Groovy code:
new File("test_csv_files/results.csv").delete()


but i want the values when the test execution starts. so, i can't format the cells. is there any other way to do the formatting the cells.....?? help me in this question thank you in advance

It's a matter of visualization in Excel, try opening it with i.e. notepad or other text editor and you will see normal numbers without scientific notation
